# HTML CSS - Can you define a class with an image using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Something like this

HTML

```
<button class="img">This button has an image</button>
<button class="img">This button has the same image</button>
```

CSS

```
.img {
        url: '/testimage.png'
}
```

Comment: you mean a background image? Use background-image....[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)

Comment: yessir.........

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [background-image](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) property.

```
.img {
  background-image: url("testimage.png");
}
```